# Why is a namespace prefix being added to elements when using XDocument.Parse(), and how to supress them?

Tags: c#, xml, linq

when I try parsing the following xml string

```
       string input = 
           @"<root xmlns=""urn:hl7-org:v3"" xmlns:abc=""urn:hl7-org:v3"" xmlns:xsi=""http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"" xsi:schemaLocation=""urn:hl7-org:v3 http://xreg2.nist.gov:8080/hitspValidation/schema/cdar2c32/infrastructure/cda/C32_CDA.xsd"" xmlns:sdtc=""urn:hl7-org:sdtc"" >" +
           @"<realmCode code=""US"" />" +
           @"<typeId root=""2"" extension=""P"" />" +
           @"<templateId root=""1"" />" +
           @"<id root=""21"" extension=""273"" />" +
           @"</root >";
```

Using System.Xml.Linq.XDocument as follows

```
XDocument _xmlObject = XDocument.Parse(input, LoadOptions.PreserveWhitespace);
```

All my tags become prefixed like this

```
<abc:root xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:abc="urn:hl7-org:v3" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="urn:hl7-org:v3 http://xreg2.nist.gov:8080/hitspValidation/schema/cdar2c32/infrastructure/cda/C32_CDA.xsd" xmlns:sdtc="urn:hl7-org:sdtc">
<abc:realmCode code="US" />
  <abc:typeId root="2" extension="P" />
  <abc:templateId root="1" />
  <abc:id root="21" extension="273" />
</abc:root>
```

Why is the parser doing this?  I don't see any options for the Parse method to suppress these.  Is there a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my view the result you see is caused by a shortcoming of the LINQ to XML object model, it does not store the prefix of the qualified name of a node, rather it only stores the local name and the namespace URI and tries to infer the prefix from any in-scope namespace declarations. In your sample there are two namespace declarations for the namespace `urn:hl7-org:v3`, the default namespace declaration `xmlns="urn:hl7-org:v3"` and the one with the prefix `xmlns:abc="urn:hl7-org:v3"`. That is perfectly fine and allowed by the XML and XML namespace specification, but it leaves the prefix inference with a choice which in your case does not reflect the prefix in the input. I don't think there is way around it using LINQ to XML (other than changing the order of the namespace declarations and hoping that the inference will consistently rely on that), the DOM implementation (`System.Xml.XmlNode/XmlElement/XmlDocument`) is an object model which stores the prefix of a qualified name and would preserve the input prefix. It has an API, however, that is not as well integrated into C# as LINQ to XML.

Answer (score 0):

It's a quite possible that your compilator when see xmlns:abc=""urn:hl7-org:v3"" then it adds this prefix to XML elements. You probably need to remove fragment of this code. I checked your problem in my compiler.

Comment: yes I found that too, when i remove the extra namespace attribute for that prefix, there are not more prefix on the tags